# Search in a list

Tags: android, search

I am trying to implement a search menu for my app.I made a menu "seach",in onOptionsItemSelected I have:

```
if (item.getItemId()==R.id.search) {
            onSearchRequested();

            return(true);
```

I put in strings.xml :

```
<string name="searchLabel">Lists</string>
  <string name="searchHint">search</string>
```

and in searchable.xml :

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/searchLabel"
        android:hint="@string/searchHint" />
```

but nothing happens after I type something. What means "Lists" from strings.xml?

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered in Android developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html):

Comment: I know this. I need some help,to tell me if I forgot something to put.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you need to tell Android about your search activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```